# How to contact a company page owner

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I know there is a flag feature to flag a job but I'm not sure that is the route to take.  How do passerby's of the site report stuff like this:

[image]

Do I flag the job listing and state that it needs cleaning up, or do I just let it go and chuckle it off - in this case.

Comment: Well, *are* you a fluent English? You're clearly not going to get the job if not.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - Shouldn't it be "You are fluent in English" rather than "You are a fluent English" a fluent english is not a physical thing, its a trait or quality.

Comment: I know, merely gently ribbing the job ad. Could also be "you are a fluent English speaker".

Comment: Well that is my point, how do we address this..obviously we cannot open it up to edits like q and a.

Comment: This sounds like they are trying to make a joke. Of course, it threw me off the first one or two times I tried to read it.

Comment: Sounds to me they're trying make a joke, it's actually quite uncommon when talking about English skills in business.

Comment: Perhaps they meant "affluent"

Comment: Clearly **they** aren't a fluent english.

Comment: * passers-by...

Answer (score 20):

Simply flag the listing and explain the issue. We'll contact the employer.

[image]

Comment: -1 for missed opportunity to use a hand drawn circle.