# Featured company has strange characters

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

This company **Vertrio Ltd** seems to be causing some bad text in the featured company section:

[image]

Comment: [flag it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312904/319875)

Comment: @FlorinGhita - That is flagging a job listing not a company page.

Comment: @FlorinGhita - See this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312723/flagging-a-job-is-fine-but-is-it-possible-to-flag-a-company-page

Comment: Guess they like Zalgo a lot. :P

Comment: Possibly a transient issue while we've been moving pieces around between Careers and Stack Overflow. The benefits section of this particular company page looks fine, and so do the "benefits" company page ads. If this appears again, please feel free to report here and we'll investigate further.