# Jobs company page spam

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, spam, companies-page

It seems that spammers are using Stack Overflow Jobs company pages to make SEO-optimized clickbait. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/-MEGA-HD-X-Men-Apocalypse-2016-Online-Free-Full) (don't ask me how I found it).

There's no option for users to flag these pages - so how do we stop the spam when we see it?

Comment: Grrmbl ... extend  [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/charcoal-se/smokedetector/wiki) to company pages ......

Comment: Thanks for reporting - that company page is now down.

Comment: @Oded There's a lot more, like http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/outlander-season-2-episode-11-vengeance-is-mine and http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/watch-trailer-the-conjuring-2-free-streaming-2016.

Comment: @hichris123 - removing them as we find them.

Comment: Well, here's a bunch @Oded: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?searchTerm=%22online+free%22.

Comment: @hichris123 - yeah, a couple of hundred, looks like. Getting through the list and looking at options to ban them.

Comment: OK, I think we cleared the lot. Definitely a bot using a botnet for these. Thanks for reporting. //cc @hichris123

Comment: @Oded I presume it wouldn't be feasible to just let SO mods delete these?

Comment: I don't believe so, not without a bunch of dev work at the moment. Not a crazy idea though, @Undo

Comment: Yeah, figured it'd be difficult with the weird proxy thing going on there @Oded. Anyway, let me know if I can help at all.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, @Undo. Will mention to the team.

Comment: The question "how do we stop the spam when we see it" still stands, @Oded...is a Meta post the best way? The _contact us_ form?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - for a longer term solution, a meta post discussing the issue and how to resolve (scale, speed, community involvement etc...) it would be the way to go. For faster resolution in the interim? Possibly an email to careers at stackoverflow.com or pinging a dev in a chat room.

Comment: @Oded I put together a [list below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326480) of all the ones I found. I hope it helps!

Comment: I think that Company pages may have been originally intended for some of the role that Team pages are adopting, which is why they're open to non-advertisers. (Which, I should note, has been very useful in allowing me to test sections of the site I wouldn't otherwise have access to.)

Comment: Related: *[Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/)* (2022-01)

Answer (score 87):

It appears that *anyone* can create a Company Page. From [the FAQ](http://business.stackoverflow.com/careers/us/faqs):

> **Do I have to have active job listings to create a Company Page?**
>
> Nope. You can create a free Company Page without job listings.
>   However, to promote your page to more developers through Company Page
>   ads, you will need to have active job listings running.

In just a few seconds, I created an account on Jobs and nearly created a Company Page. It shouldn't be that easy.

**Please restrict the people who can create a Company Page.** I'm not sure if it would be best to make it only available if you want to create a listing, but quite obviously one shouldn't be able to create a Company Page and just leave it there. Otherwise, this is a spammers haven -- someone can create a page and have it indexed by Google, all without paying.

Comment: I think company pages should be private (hidden from view) until the company posts their first listing. From that point on, even without listings, it would remain public.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter That would certainly stop a bit of spam, for a second. The problem is that if people are botting the company pages now, they'll just adjust their bot to include a listing.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice [Listings are flaggable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312895/how-to-contact-a-company-page-owner/312904#312904), [company pages are not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312723/flagging-a-job-is-fine-but-is-it-possible-to-flag-a-company-page), so requiring a listing might facilitate cleanup, at least.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Also, for a listing, you have to pay. Defeats the purpose of spamming if you have to pay. ;)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom & Chris - I didn't know that, but that would definitely make sense. Why would you create a page without having a listing? Requiring a listing seems like a very quick and efficient way of stopping spam.

Comment: You don't even have to require a listing -- just don't have Google index the page unless there's one currently active or there has been one that wasn't flagged into nonexistence.

Answer (score 58):

I'm finding a number of spammy company pages, and it's getting too awkward to use the tiny comment boxes. I'm marking this Community Wiki so that everyone else can add to or edit the list.

The main sign that I've been seeing that something is wrong is that the "benefits" are not benefits. While I have found some [false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/contus), the vast majority that follow this pattern are breaking [the rules](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules):

> Company pages on Stack Overflow Careers are specifically meant to promote your company to potential hires, and the content and language should reflect this. This is not the place to advertise the services of your company to potential clients, advertise jobs (other than those posted on careers), or invite people to recruiting events.

---

I think that we need to be more clear what the job pages are for. I have only found two vague paragraphs about company pages. The lack of clear guidelines is probably a contributor to some of the spam/noise we have. I suspect that some companies haven't read the rules (or don't speak English and used Google Translate).

The rules should be prominently displayed where they can be seen without needing to create an account or login. They should mention:

- This is not the place for companies (or individuals) to post if they are looking to be hired. No CVs!
- There must be some mention of what it will be like to work there ("benefits").

  - Some good examples: work 10 miles from beach, flexible hours, 401k, etc.
  - Some bad examples: $500 referral fee, responsive web design, 20 years experience, etc.
- Pages that read like an advertisement for the company will be removed
- What the policy on multiple company pages is. I can't answer this, but I think that having more than one company page with identical or nearly identical content is stupid and should not be allowed. If so, that should be its own list.

---

Also, I noticed link shorteners aren't blocked. They probably should be...

---

### The list

To keep things organized, this section should only contain pages that are still live so that it's easy for the "powers that delete" to do their job. As these pages are deleted, the links can be removed. (You can use the revision history to see the dead links.)

- Add a link here!

Comment: I looked through and found ~20 but I already pinged someone about them. Not sure if it's worth adding them to this list. https://gist.github.com/hichris1234/dd8ec804e95fa48ce343df456dfb5fa8

Comment: That Russian one tho: "_i write code, code, code_" "_write code, and write code_" "_for hours write code_"

Comment: @Tas Founded in 1976...I guess they have been writing code for a long time

Comment: @brimstone I assume that "founded in 1976" was when they were born. Somebody should get a screenshot or download the source of that page before it's gone.

Comment: @Laurel I downloaded as a PDF. Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/822bm6vse310vjb/http___stackoverflow_com_jobs_companies_webwizengine.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @Oded Just added two more at the bottom of the list.  They clearly should both be deleted.